# Using eslint with travis CI

Tags: javascript, npm, travis-ci, eslint

I am trying to setup a travis CI for my repo on github and I want to run an eslint as one of the checks in the build, this is my .travis.yml config file content

```
language: node_js
cache:
  directories:
    - "node_modules"
sudo: false
script:
  - "npm run lint"
```

The problem I have is when I run npm run lint locally it works correctly but on travis it fails with a strange error. The [build log is here](https://travis-ci.org/openwisp/netjsonconfig-editor.js/jobs/241273978).

When I run `npm run lint` locally all I get are these line:

```
>netjsonconfig-editor.js@1.0.0 lint /home/elastic/netjsonEditor
>eslint --fix src/js/**.js
```

my eslintrc file is asbelow:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "strict": 1,
    "comma-spacing":1,
    "no-console":0,
    "indent": ["error", "tab"]
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "script",
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": false,
    "codeFrame": false
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "globals": {
    "require": true,
    "module": true
  },
  "env":{
    "browser":true
  }
}
```

Any idea why this may be failing?

Comment: Could you add the logs when you try it locally?

Comment: All i get when i run it locally is this:
`> netjsonconfig-editor.js@1.0.0 lint /home/elastic/netjsonEditor
> eslint --fix src/js/**.js `

Comment: Could you put it in the question, and it doesn't look like all the messages eslint would log

Comment: but that's actually all I got

Comment: Ok, could you post you eslint configuration file, clearly the build log said something about `strict mode` and that const isn't allowed, maybe it is in your configuration

Comment: posted it in the question

Comment: I am sure that setting the strict option to 0, would solve the problem but I think this is not the right way of doing this

Comment: Ok, also you are running this for the browser, so you shouldn't use `const` and `let`, as it is not a browser standart

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I was wondering if you ever got this fixed?